# I destroyed my code and want to recover a previous date in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, history, revert

Hello I made a big mistake and destroyed my code in android studio.
Is there a way through the local history to revert the hole app to a previous state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you'll have to use `Show history` for each file, and revert the code to the right version.

To do that, right click anywhere in a file in AS editor, click on `Local History` and then `Show History`. At this point, dialog will open where you'll have a list of all saved versions of a file and the option to revert to any of them.

**EDIT:**

PS: You might want to start using version control (like git), even if you don't want to push your code to online repository. It gives you clean way of reverting code to latest commit, reverting commits, etc.

Comment: Thank you you saved me!